# MongoDB hanging count query on collection with large objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with 10.000 objects. Each object's size is around 500kb since they include images in them. For statistics, I need to count objects with their creation time. Even though I have indexes, counting the whole collection takes more than 15 seconds. When I remove the `image` field (i.e the object becomes a simple JSON object), the query immediately returns. I do not understand why size of the objects affects performance this much. Here is a sample query I have been using:

```
const aggregation = [
   {"$match": {"createTime": {"$gte": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}},
   {"$match": {"createTime": {"$lte": "2020-01-01T23:59:59.999Z"}}},
   {"$count": "value"}];
myCollection.aggregate(aggregation).then(foo);
```

Is there a way to make the query faster?

One solution I could think of is to store images in a separate collection. This will definitely make the query faster but I am wondering the reason behind this performance drop.

Answer (score 1):

500KB * 10000 documents is 5.1GB to examine.  That might take a few seconds, especially if your cache is smaller than that.

Try doing this with a `count` query instead.

Assuming there is an index on `createTime`, and no document in the collection contains an array for that field (i.e. the index is not multikey), this query should be able to be fully covered.

This means that they query executor should use a COUNTSCAN stage to find the number of matching documents by scanning the index, and never need to look at a single document, which means document size no longer matters, and it should cut down on your disk IO, cache churn, and CPU utilization as well.

```
db.myCollection.count({"createTime": {"$gte": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"},"createTime": {"$lte": "2020-01-01T23:59:59.999Z"}})`
```

Comment: I am also running count queries with grouping. For example, a query that returns count of objects for each city. (Assume that each object has city field). I don't think I can achieve this in that way.

Comment: That is true, you couldn't get multiple counts at once.  So the tradeoff is time and IO.  You can run dozens of counts in the time an aggregation pipeline would take to read all of the documents, so whether it is more efficient to use a single aggregation pipeline or run several count queries will depend on the data and your query requirements. i.e. YMMV, you should probably test.